# action dispatch does not work after passing value in event handler function

Tags: react-redux

I am learning redux and mock the teacher's code,I just change a little,but I do not know why it can not work,and I want to try plenty of ways to adjust it,but it is too little too try and nowhere could start.Below is the code causing bug I guess because the project could not work while I write a little in it.The below is almost 100% with Dan Abramov's version`https://embed.plnkr.co/github/eggheadio-projects/getting-started-with-redux/master/23-react-redux-extracting-container-components-visibletodolist-addtodo?show=script,preview`

```
const Deeplists = ({ store }) => {
  const [_, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);
  store.subscribe(forceUpdate);
  return (
    <Lists
      todos={deepertodos(
        store.getState().todos,
        store.getState().visibilityFilter
      )}
      onTodoClick={id=> store.dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_TODO", id })}
    />
  );
};
```

This is my project link:https://codepen.io/nutkin/pen/PopOamN?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to avoid to use store.dispatch method and replace with connect